# TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined when instantiating an object

Tags: typescript

Here is my class and interface :

```
export interface Foo{
    numFoo: string
}

export class Blah{
  constructor(
    public numBlah: string,
    public arrayOfFoos: Array<Foo>,
    public idBlah: string
    ) { }
}

let numBlah: string = 'numBlah'
let arr: Array<Foo> =[{numFoo: '1'}]
let idBlah: string = 'id'
let blah = new Blah(numBlah, arr, idBlah)
```

I just expect to instantiate a new Blah item by passing arguments directly (not mentionning the name of the fields). Any idea why I am having this error ?

Comment: Your code compiles and runs correctly for me, what version of typescript are you using?

Comment: My typescript version is 2.1.6

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code you're using? It looks fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to reformat your code to old-school OOP version:

```
export interface Foo {
    numFoo: string;
}

export class Blah {

    public numBlah: string;
    public arrayOfFoos: Foo[];
    public idBlah: string;

    constructor (numBlah: string, arrayOfFoos: Foo[], idBlah: string) {
        this.numBlah = numBlah;
        this.arrayOfFoos = arrayOfFoos;
        this.idBlah = idBlah;
    }

}

let numBlah: string = 'numBlah';
let arr: Foo[] = [{ numFoo: '1' }];
let idBlah: string = 'id';

let blah = new Blah(numBlah, arr, idBlah);

console.log(blah.idBlah);
```